# Is it correct to say "That needs fixed" rather than "That needs to be fixed?"

Tags: grammar, colloquialisms

A person I know often drops the "to be" which would normally be before the verb in a sentence.  He'll say things like:

- That needs fixed.
- It needs upgraded.
- They need looked at.

rather than

- That needs *to be* fixed.
- It needs *to be* upgraded.
- They need *to be* looked at.

Is this just a personal quirk?  Is it colloquial or archaic?  It it grammatically correct?  Does it have a name?

Comment: It's called *reduction* of function words. It's very informal.

Comment: If you want to avoid the extra "to be", simply say "That needs fixing."

Comment: All this discussion and all of the discussion on the "duplicate" posts is just amateur sociolinguistics. The phenomenon has been studied by professionals and the details are available at https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/needs-washed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping the "to be" is grammatically incorrect, and colloquialisms are words or phrases, not habits, so it isn't a colloquialism. It's actually a regional dialect, used often in the southern United States but most famously attributed to Pittsburghese: http://theglassblock.com/2016/07/07/pittsburghese-expertise-dropping-to-be/

If you want to see more people who do this, look here:
https://www.facebook.com/GrammarGirl/posts/10150827196390228

The umbrella term for this habit is *zero copula*, but I don't believe there is any other (aside from *needs verbed*).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_copula
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)#Zero_copula